# Can a Leader's Burst Healing work if there is a blocking wall?

Tags: dnd-4e, healing, line-of-sight, line-of-effect, leader

Most of the Leader's in 4th edition have a **`close burst 5`**   **Healing** power.

If the target of the **Healing** power is completely blocked by a wall from the **Leader**, can the Leader still heal the target?

If the Leader has neither line-of-sight or line-of-effect can she still heal a target?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**,

**Bursts** <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=126)</sup> do not go through walls. Because:

> A burst affects a target only if there is line of effect from the burst’s origin square to the target.

A **line of effect** <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=543)</sup> is

> A clear line from one point to another point in an encounter that doesn’t pass through or touch blocking terrain.

Walls are the first example given for **Blocking Terrain** <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=504)</sup>.

Answer (score 4):

**No**,

bursts (and blasts and walls) require line of effect (that is blocked by walls) from their origin square. They don't require line of sight.